# How do I append an object so it is still correctly connected to its armature?

Tags: armature, workflow, append

What are the tips for appending so that it works well? I tried to append but when the object comes in to the scene it's fractured e.g. bones don't fit the object, there seems to be multiple meshes etc.

Should I append in some specific order so that things come in the right place? First object, then bones, then material, etc.? I have the relative path set to ON if that helps.

The object is 'Sintel' from blender swap.

Comment: sintel should have groups available, selecting one of the groups should import all relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

I foundt out that using the group appending was the key to this problem .

Comment: Can you elaborate?